# Any way to view current Song and media controls in XFCE?

Tags: xfce, media

When running Spotify within Unity, the audio icon in the top right of the screen shows the currently playing song as well as media controls to go back, forward, play and pause.  I'm assuming this is a generic system that works with more than just Spotify (especially since Spotify requires a ppa).

Is there any way to have this same functionality in an XFCE panel?  My attempts at searching haven't turned up much but I"m not sure of the exact terms to search for.

Comment: In case your keyboard has multimedia keys and you'd also like to set those up to work with Spotify in Xfce, it's pretty easy: https://askubuntu.com/a/925837/18665

Comment: omg thanks for that.  Ever since I reinstalled I've been trying to find out to remap those shortcuts but my google-fu was failing.

Comment: To be fair there seem to be a dozen ways to do it, but that seemed the cleanest since it didn't involve installing extra packages or creating extra files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Xubuntu 18.04

In Xubuntu 18.04, [this functionality is provided by the PulseAudio Plugin](https://wiki.xubuntu.org/releases/18.04/release-notes#pulseaudio_plugin). If you've upgraded from an earlier version, it may not be in your panel. To add it:

1. Make sure the old sound indicator package is removed

   ```
   sudo apt remove indicator-sound
   ```
2. Make sure the PulseAudio Plugin is installed

   ```
   sudo apt install xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin
   ```
3. Make sure the PulseAudio Plugin is in your panel

   1. Right-click the panel > *Panel* > *Panel Preferences* > *Items*
   2. Make sure *PulseAudio Plugin* is in the list. Add it if not.

It should look something like this when you're done:
[image: PulseAudio Plugin]

#### Xubuntu 17.10 and below

1. Install the `indicator-sound` package

   ```
   sudo apt install indicator-sound
   ```
2. Make sure the sound indicator is set to visible

   ```
   gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound visible true
   ```
3. Log out and log back in
4. If you still don't see the sound indicator, right-click the panel > *Panel* > *Panel Preferences* > *Items*
5. Make sure *Indicator Plugin* is in the list. Add it if not.
6. Select *Indicator Plugin* > *Edit* (the gear icon)
7. Make sure *Sound Menu* is in the list
8. If *Sound Menu* still isn't in the list, click *Clear known indicators*
9. If the indicator still doesn't show up, try restarting the panel

   ```
   xfce4-panel -r
   ```

It should look something like this when you're done:
[image: Xubuntu 16.04 sound indicator]

Comment: Apparently I"m an idiot and never noticed that the audio indicator had that :(